# How to restrict gerrit repository options configurations?

Tags: gerrit

Right now anyone belonging to a generic group can change repository options configurations like state, submit type, etc. How do I restrict this to just a certain group? Thinking maybe it's in the ACL?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Someone can change repository options if he/she has the "ALLOW" permission in the "Owner" control access on "refs/*" reference:

[image]

See more details in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html) and [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#project_owners).